# Android: how to call onCreate() with different arguments after clicking on a list item?

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String path = "/";
    ...

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}
```

I'd like to call onCreate() again inside the OnItemClickListener function but with "path" variable set differently (based on what's clicked).

I had a look at "Intent" class but it didn't help me much. I'm not sure what to look for.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnItemClick you have to have something like this:

```
Object curlistItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

To see which item is being clicked, then take necessary action.

Comment: How can I get the value of the TextView from that object? I mean, my clicked list item had a text object in it. I need that value.

Comment: You can do this: Cursor cCursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);   then you'll have selected item text in cCursor.getString(1)

Comment: String TheStr = (String)((Cursor)list.getItemAtPosition(position)).getString(1);

Comment: You should change my code to your variables and put them on right location, not copy paste, are you sure you are doing it right? Last code I gave you works well

Comment: getString(1) could be getString(2) or 3 or 0 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better not invoke onCreate again by yourself. You can have your own method doing the initialization e.g. init(...).

In onCreate you can invoke init(...), and in click listener you can invoke you own init(...) method as you wished.